# Routing bot-traffic to different server with Lambda edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying to route traffic coming from bots (Google, Facebook etc.) to an entirely different server hosted with elastic beanstalk on AWS.

When looking for examples, I only come across people who route their traffic to another S3 bucket like this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

  let is_crawler = undefined;
  if ('is-crawler' in request['headers']) {
    is_crawler = request['headers']['is-crawler'][0].value.toLowerCase();
  }
  if (is_crawler === 'true') {
    request.origin = {
      s3: {
        authMethod: 'origin-access-identity',
        path: '',
        domainName: 'redacted.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
        region: 'eu-west-1,
        customHeaders: {}
      }
    };
  }
  callback(null, request);
};
```

I don't really seem to understand the `request.origin` object yet. I don't understand why it would have a property dedicated to s3? And I also don't understand how I would use this code to route the traffic to a server like `api.<domainname>.com`.

Has someone solved this before?

Answer (score 1):

I will post an answer I recieved on reddit for this because I generally like SO questions that help for future reference:

> The idea is that you have multiple origins defined in CloudFront and
>   that you can dynamically select which one to forward the request to in
>   your Lambda@Edge function. There's no requirement that it is forwarded
>   to an S3 Origin - that's just a common use case for static assets or
>   static websites.
>
> For your example, if you have 2 custom origins, you can use this as
>   example as a starting point:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-content-based-geo-header
>   Instead of the country header, you would probably use UserAgent or
>   remote ip address.

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/fawh6l/routing_bottraffic_to_different_server_with/

This helped me solve it.